# Java program doesn't terminate. Neither does it shows any output

Tags: java, data-structures

My Java program regarding Stacks made from LinkedLists. The task at hand was to merge two sorted stacks into one. I think I figured it out but it won't show any output and also it doesn't terminate. Can anyone help?

The "next" instance is pointing to the LinkedList's next element's address in the memory.

```
void mergeStacks()
    {
        Stacks sortedMain = new Stacks();
        Stacks sorted1 = new Stacks();
        Stacks sorted2 = new Stacks();
        sorted1.push(1);
        sorted1.push(2);
        sorted1.push(3);
        sorted2.push(4);
        sorted2.push(5);
        sorted2.push(6);
        
        System.out.println("Stack 1");
        sorted1.displayStack();
        System.out.println("Stack 2");
        sorted2.displayStack();
        
        Node q = sorted1.head,p = sorted2.head,x = sortedMain.head;
        
        while(q.next != null)
        {
            if(x == null)
            {
                sortedMain.push(sorted1.pop());
            }
            while(x.next != null)
            {
                sortedMain.push(sorted1.pop());
                x = x.next;
            }
            q = q.next;
        }
        
        while(p.next != null)
        {
            while(x.next != null)
            {
                sortedMain.push(sorted2.pop());
                x = x.next;
            }
            p = q.next;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Merged Stack\n");
        sortedMain.displayStack();
    }
```

So, I figured out the thing that is causing the console to not show anything. Apparently, the function "pop()" is not really returning int for some reason. Here's the method:

```
int pop()
{
    int popped = 0;
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        Node q = head;
        while(q.next != null)
        {
            if(q.next.next == null)
            {
                popped = q.data;
                q.next = null;
                top = q;
            }
        }
    }
    return popped;
}
```

[Output(With Debugger)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRIzc.png)

Comment: What happens when you run your code through your debugger?

Comment: i have added the image showing the output and after working my way through all the LOC, nothing shows up except this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this inside the first while loop, which makes no sense:

```
if(x == null)
{
    sortedMain.push(sorted1.pop());
}
while(x.next != null)
{
    sortedMain.push(sorted1.pop());
    x = x.next;
}
```

When x is null in the first `if` statement, how can you then use it in the next `while` statement?  That should produce a null reference exception...

It seems like maybe you think that `x` would be somehow updated to the new head when you push something into an empty `sortedMain`? It won't be.

Also, is the "merged" stack supposed to be sorted?  Your code appears to be trying to simply push all of the first sorted stack in, followed by pushing all of the second sorted stack in.  This may or may not result in an overall sorted stack...depends on the elements within.

What I think should happen is you pop just the first two from each list and do a comparison, pushing whatever is greater/smaller (you didn't specify a sort order).  Then you pop the next one from the side that was pushed and repeat.  If one side becomes empty, then you'd simply push all the rest from the other side.

---

From the comments:

> I don't really have to define an order in what they are going to
> merge. I just want to merge them in whatever order they are into a
> third stack. My strategy is to traverse through the first stack and
> push all the elements into the main stack and do the same with the
> next one.

Did you implement an `isEmpty()` method for your `Stacks` class?  If so, this is what most people would expect to see:

```
while(!sorted1.isEmpty())
{
    sortedMain.push(sorted1.pop());
}

while(!sorted2.isEmpty())
{
    sortedMain.push(sorted2.pop());
}
```

If you haven't implemented an `isEmpty()` type method, then you could check to see if the `head` is null instead?  (*I'm assuming you correctly set that to null when the stack is empty!):

```
while(sorted1.head != null)
{
    sortedMain.push(sorted1.pop());
}

while(sorted2.head != null)
{
    sortedMain.push(sorted2.pop());
}
```

Comment: I don't really have to define an order in what they are going to merge. I just want to merge them in whatever order they are into a third stack. My strategy is to traverse through the first stack and push all the elements into the main stack and do the same with the next one.